# Sorting by ratings in a database - Where to put this SQL? (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, database, database-design, mysql

OK - I'll get straight to the point - here's the PHP code in question:

```
<h2>Highest Rated:</h2>

    <?php 

        // Our query base               
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM code ORDER BY rating DESC");

        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    ?>  
        <h3><?php echo $row->title." ID: ";echo $row->id; ?></h3>
            <p class="author"><?php  $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = ".$row->author);
echo $query2->row('email');?></p>
            <?php   echo ($this->bbcode->Parse($row->code)); ?>

        <?php } ?>
```

Sorry it's a bit messy, it's still a draft. Anyway, I researched ways to use a Ratings system - previously I had a single 'rating' field as you can see by SELECT * FROM code ORDER BY rating DESC. However I quickly realised calculating averages like that wasn't feasible, so I created five new columns - rating1, rating2, rating3, rating4, rating5. So when 5 users rating something 4 stars, rating4 says 5... does that make sense? Each ratingx column counts the number of times the rating was given.

So anyway: I have this SQL statement:

`SELECT id, (ifnull(rating1,0) + ifnull(rating2,0) + ifnull(rating3,0) + ifnull(rating4,0) + ifnull(rating5,0)) /
          ((rating1 IS NOT NULL) + (rating2 IS NOT NULL) + (rating3 IS NOT NULL) + (rating4 IS NOT NULL) + (rating5 IS NOT NULL)) AS average FROM code`

Again messy, but hey. Now what I need to know is how can I incorporate that SQL statement into my script? Ideally you'd think the overall query would be 'SELECT * FROM code ORDER BY (*that really long query i just stated*) DESC' but I can't quite see that working... how do I do it? Query, store the result in a variable, something like that?

If that makes no sense sorry! But I really appreciate the help :)

Jack

Comment: Jack, does your REALLY long query indeed work?

Comment: Please update your question to show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE code\G`. Also, the multiple columns for rating is almost guaranteed to be a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I hope you can understand I am a beginner! I was aware of SQL joins but not necessarily that I should use them here and will be. And I've just read over what I wrote again... My apologies, my mind was too numb from coding all evening to comprehend! :D

I'll rethink my code from scratch and if I still need help, repost. Thank you :)

Comment: @jeroen, the world if full of know-it-alls with enough points to vote on SO.

Comment: Yup, I saw them all on -1 - I really appreciate the advice and voted them all back up, although I'm not sure who did it (I do t have enough points to vote down yet...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should go back to the drawing board completely.

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM code ORDER BY rating DESC");
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = ".$row->author;
}
```

*Anytime* you see this in your code, stop what you're doing immediately. This is what JOINs are for. You almost never want to loop over the results of a query and issue multiple queries from within that loop.

```
SELECT code.*, users.email 
FROM code
JOIN users ON users.id = code.author
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

This query will grab all that data in a single resultset, removing the N+1 query problem.

I'm not addressing the rest of your question until you clean up your question some and clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd also just echo out the simple things like `H3` from PHP and not bounce between html and PHP all the time for those trivial things

Comment: why was this downvoted? this looks like sensible advice to me?!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I am still learning, but thank you, I really appreciate it :) I guess we all have to begin somewhere :P

Comment: And Roland, all seemed to be downvoted. I voted everything back up to 0, I agree with you...

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to change your tables again, here is my suggestion:

why don't you store two columns: RatingTotal and RatingCount, each user that rates it will increment RatingCount by one, and whatever they vote (5,4,4.2, etc) is added to RatingTotal.  You could then just ORDER BY RatingTotal/RatingCount

also, I hope you store which users rated each item, so they don't vote multiple times! and swing the average their way.

Comment: Thanks, knowing me I'd have forgotten to incorporate checking which users have already voted ;)

Comment: create a rating table, with user, item, rating, and a date in it. you could use this to calculate average rating with, however storing the aggregate in the item can simplify and speed up your other queries.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd decide whether your application is write-heavy or read-heavy.  If there are a lot more reads than writes, then you want to minimize the amount of work you do on reads (like this script, for example).  On the assumption that it's read-heavy, since most webapps are, I'd suggest maintaining the combined average in a separate column and recalculating it whenever a user adds a new rating.

Other options are:

- Try ordering by the calculated column name 'average'.  SQL Server supports this. . not sure about mysql.
- Use a view.  You can create a view on your base table that does the average calculation for you and you can query against that.

Also, unrelated to your question, don't do a separate query for each user in your loop.  Join the users table to the code table in the original query.

Comment: Thanks - it's going to be read-heavy, definitely. Thank you for your help - as you can tell I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1):

You should include it in the SELECT part:

```
SELECT *, (if ....) AS average FROM ... ORDER BY average
```

**Edit:** assuming that your ifnull statement actually works...

You might also want to look into joins to avoid querying the database again for every user; you can do everything in 1 select statement.

Apart from that I would also say that you only need one average and the number of total votes, that should give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

Some excellent ideas, but I think the best way (as sidereal said that it's more read heavy that write heavy) would be to have columns rating and times_rated, and just do something like this:

```
new_rating = ((times_rated * rating) + current_rating) / (times_rated + 1)
```

current_rating being the rating being applied when the person clicks the little stars.  This simply weights the current user's rating in an average with the current rating.