# How to get records ordered by rating desc

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables i.e hostel and rating. How to display the records order by rating from two tables.may i request you give some idea about this

```
|------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|       hotel table is         |      rating table is               |
|------------------------------|------------------------------------|
|post_id  | user_id  | hostel  |r_id |  user_id | post_id  | rating |
|   1     |     2    |  xyz    |  2  |   2      |   1      |   5    |
|   3     |     4    |  abc    |  4  |   4      |   1      |   3    |
|   5     |     6    |  ijk    |  5  |   6      |   6      |   4    |
|   6     |     7    |  pqr    |  6  |   7      |   6      |   5    |
|   8     |     8    |  mno    |  7  |   8      |   5      |   5    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please add your table names and query

Comment: that edit saved you from lots of down-votes. anyway I think you just need `order by rating desc`

Comment: Actually  there is  some condition ex: if post_id 's are 10,12 then for 10 there are 20 users given 5 rating and 5 users given 3 rating ,for 12 there are  5 users give 5 rating and 20 users given 3 rating in this the display order should be like highest users with 5 rating i.e 20 users given 5 will be first

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM hotel inner join rating ON hotel.post_id = rating.post_id ORDER BY rating.rating DESC";
```

Comment: Actually  there is  some condition ex: if post_id 's are 10,12 then for 10 there are 20 users given 5 rating and 5 users given 3 rating ,for 12 there are  5 users give 5 rating and 20 users given 3 rating in this the display order should be like highest users with 5 rating i.e 20 users given 5 will be first

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select *
from hotel h join rating r
using (post_id, user_id)
order by rating desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM hotel_table 
LEFT JOIN rating_table ON hotel_table.post_id = rating_table.post_id 
ORDER BY rating_table.rating DESC";
```

Try this

Comment: Actually  there is  some condition ex: if post_id 's are 10,12 then for 10 there are 20 users given 5 rating and 5 users given 3 rating ,for 12 there are  5 users give 5 rating and 20 users given 3 rating in this the display order should be like highest users with 5 rating i.e 20 users given 5 will be first

Comment: checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314683/sorting-by-ratings-in-a-database-where-to-put-this-sql-php-mysql

Comment: this one is also usefull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061586/sort-by-highest-average-rating